# show articles only in featured page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, acl

```
http://example.com/products/2-uncategorised/
http://example.com/products/2-uncategorised/2-aaa-bb-ccccc
```

I have this structure, where products is a featured page with articles. What I want is just block the access to the category and related articles.

So, `http://example.com/products/2-uncategorised/` or `http://example.com/products/2-uncategorised/2-aaa-bb-ccccc` should redirect to `http://example.com/products`.

The only way that i know is:

```
#RedirectMatch 301 ^/products/.*$ http://www.example.com/products
```

Note: If I change the permissions of the article, available only to Registered users then the article is removed from the featured page if the user is not registered (*wrong, this page should be **public***).

I need to preserve all articles in featured page and block the access of the individual article and the category that it belongs.

The question: There is another way without `.htaccess` ?

Comment: I'm somewhat confused by what you are asking for but have you considered using the show unauthorized option? 
I would not use the redirecting you are proposing as that could hurt your sef unless you send an unauthorized header with it.

Comment: @Elin, basically I just want to display the articles in the featured page, and joomla will automatically generate some default pages, like the /category/article_name. These pages will be available if the user type directly in the url bar.

Comment: Do you want other users to be able to go to those pages?

Comment: @Elin No, i don't have any link for those automatic pages (generated by joomla). Those pages should not exist.

Comment: Well of course they exist if you created them as articles, what you want is for them not to render.  If you are never showing a full article view why don't you make a layout override for single article that loads something besides the content such as just a blank page with a menu?

Comment: @Elin The override will only work for one specific template. Can't be an option.

Comment: How may templates can you be using? :P   Actually the other option is to use a plugin to basically block the views you dont want  and redirect to the error page.

Comment: I am not sure I got it right. You want to show featured articles that don't link to the actual articles right? If that is the case create a template override ( remove the link) OR leave the link and make a custom query so you can grab the featured articles even if the are for Registered users only.

Answer (score -1):

What is the problem with having multiple paths to the same article?

Are you worried about the user experience or the effect on your SEO?
If it's the later then you have some control over this.
Using "canonical" tags, you can stipulate which is the master URL for Google et al to index.

You can also manipulate the robots setting for each category or menu item.

If it's the former, I certainly wouldn't recommend redirects in htaccess.  If you absolutely must redirect, use the redirect component that comes with Joomla. Still not recommended for this.

Why don't you do away with the featured page and just use articles with their own hidden menu items. This will give a direct access, no category view.  If you want to add other articles to the bottom in a blog like style, you could add articles to modules and get a similar effect?